# ng v is working in cmd but not working in vs code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

SO i wanted to create an web application so i downloaded VS code and node.js the current version and i installed everything successfully. 
When i type  ng v in cmd i am able to view the version of angular but when i open a folder and run the same command in vs code i get an error code like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
try {
process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');
} catch(_) {
// If an error happened above, use the most basic title.
process.title = 'ng';
}

// Some older versions of Node do not support let or const.
var version = process.version.substr(1).split('.');
if (Number(version[0]) < 8 || (Number(version[0]) === 8 && 
Number(version[1]) < 9)) {
process.stderr.write(
'You are running version ' + process.version + ' of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6.\n' +
'The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater.\n\n' +
'Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.\n'
);

process.exit(3);
}

require('../lib/init');
```

i know this says node version is < 8 but my node version is 12.1.0 which is clearly greater than version 8. I even tried to uninstall it and reinstall it but still i am getting this error. PLEASE HELP MEE

Comment: Try using a stable version(LTS) of node.js and try reinstalling ur VS Code!

Comment: reboot your system